# MySql select two queries in one statement

Tags: sql, database

I have bank transaction data to select two functions in a single query.
I have data like this

```
|ID  |  name  | amount |
|----|--------|--------|
| 1  |  xxx   | 1000   |
| 2  |  yyy   | -500   |
| 3  |  qqq   | 1500   |
| 4  |  ggg   | -1000  |
------------------------
```

I want like this

```
-------------------------------------------
|ID  |  name  | amount | sell | buy | cum |
|----|--------|--------|------|-----|-----|
| 1  |  xxx   | 1000   | 1000 | n/a |1000 |
| 2  |  yyy   | -500   | n/a  |-500 | 500 |
| 3  |  qqq   | 1500   | 1500 | n/a | 2000|
| 4  |  ggg   | -1000  | n/A  |-1000| 1000|
------------------------------------------
```

My code is.

```
SELECT ID, name, amount,
CASE WHEN amount >=0 THEN amount END AS sell,
CASE WHEN amount <=0 THEN amount END AS buy,
From bank
Join (select @csum := @csum + amount as csum from bank
Join (select @csum := 0) r order by ID);
```

Comment: Don't spam the tags. Pick the database engine tag you are actually using. And perhaps look at what you posted, imagine that you know nothing about the "transaction data" and evaluate whether you could make sense of it. I can't.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the datbase you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

Ther no need for multiple select  statement.

```
SELECT ID, name, amount,
CASE WHEN amount >=0 THEN amount END AS sell,
CASE WHEN amount <=0 THEN amount END AS buy,
@csum := @csum + amount as csum from bank
```

Join (select @csum := 0) r order by ID);

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write this query uses window functions:

```
SELECT ID, name, amount,
       (CASE WHEN amount >= 0 THEN amount END) AS sell,
       (CASE WHEN amount <= 0 THEN amount END) AS buy,
       SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY id) as cumulative
FROM bank;
```